# actionscript3/CS3 .fla vs .as

Tags: actionscript-3

actionscript3 is my first developing language, and I have been using it for about a week in total (so i'm a very new user). I use flash CS3 and I store all my code in the .fla file. From what I hear, this is very bad to do. Is this true? I may be misunderstanding. Also, I have no clue what the .as files are used for, but I think its to help organize all your code (all the code in my .fla should be  in separate .as files) but this doesn't sound right. Could someone help me understand 1). What is the main use of a .as file? And 2). Is it normal to store all the code in the .fla? Please excuse my small knowledge of all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIDE: If you're that new to AS, it might be better to pick up something a bit more web friendly and current. AS was a great language in it's heyday, but has largely been replaced by JS.

Storing code in the fla is OK as long as you're not working on a large project. .as files are just text files that you store in the same directory (or other directories if you want to configure Flash) as your fla. When you put code in .as files you need to organize the code into classes (one class per .as file), then import the classes for use in or on objects.

Here's a good tutorial about using classes (and therefore external as files) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233